# Create complex hasManyThrough Laravel 4 query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have classes User, User_Role and Role_Permission with correspondent tables

```
users (id)

users_roles (user_id, role_id, one user_id has one role_id)

roles_permissions (role_id, permission_id, one role_id has many permission_id)
```

I want to get permissions for user via $user->permissions. For this I wrote function

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('User_Role', 'Role_Permission', 'user_id','role_id');
}
```

I get the error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'roles_permissions.user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `users_roles`.*, `roles_permissions`.`user_id` from `users_roles` inner join `roles_permissions` on `roles_permissions`.`id` = `users_roles`.`role_id` where `roles_permissions`.`user_id` = 1)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the order of the first two arguments:

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Role_Permission', 'User_Role', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

Eloquent is looking for the `user_id` column in the `Role_Permission` table, which it won't find..

Comment: @Lambrusco haha, I did wonder if you would manage to figure it out before I could post! :)